# How to generate stub listener in salesforce

Tags: workflow, webservices

I need to know how to generate a stub listener in Salesforce. My exact requirement is to call a web service, written in APEX in one org, through an outbound message in another org.

I found below link about building a listener, but it doesn't explain how to do it in Salesforce.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_listener.htm

Thanks in advance!
Inshar

Comment: I think you can create the WSDL from apex class in salesforce and then parse that WSDL back in another org to generate apex class back and then you can call out.Even you may try using REST API also

Comment: Hi Mohith, I want to know how to create a webservice listener(using apex) for an outbound message in salesforce. (for 2 different orgs). I hope my question is clear for you.

Comment: Answer revised, sorry about the rehash !

Comment: Plz let me knw if u were able yo generate the listener in apex. If yes plz shed some light as I am also stuck

Answer (score 1):

I think I just had a bit of a brain freeze there (apologies), I don't reckon there is a way to generate a Web Service from a WSDL in Salesforce. (The import wsdl generates classes to call out to a service)

What you might be able to do is use [WSDL2Java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) and since Java is pretty close to Apex, you can then paste the generated service into your IDE as a new Class and then you will need to trim away some bits and change for Syntax differences. (eg add @Webservice annotation, etc But this will be quite a bit of work !)

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -s -o ./ <WSDLName>
```

Although to be honest, it would probably be easier just to write your own web service to respond to that notification. (You can use the Import WSDL to generate the Request and Response Classes : Setup > Develop > Class > Generate from WSDL, and then use them to write your own webservice)

Comment: Hi techtrekker, Thanks for the reply. I got your point. I want to know how to  generate the listener service (by using the outbound message wsdl) in salesforce. 
Thanks!

Comment: Added above. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi techtrekker, Thanks again! I created webservice classes. (There are 3 classes). Still, I don't see any method to get the field values and do my business logic. Please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Also, that method needs to be marked as a webservice, right?

Comment: Inshar, for creating an outbound webservice, you would need to generate the WSDL for the Apex class you wrote. Then use the salesforce provided mock classes to test.